# error installing AsyncStorage in react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to install AsyncStorage module in my react native project.

https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install

I installed the module with npm and linked it using the link command as error message suggests but I'm getting the same error message, what am I doing wrong?

Error message:

```
 ERROR  Error: [@RNC/AsyncStorage]: NativeModule: AsyncStorage is null.

To fix this issue try these steps:

  • Run `react-native link @react-native-async-storage/async-storage` in the project root.

  • Rebuild and restart the app.

  • Run the packager with `--reset-cache` flag.

  • If you are using CocoaPods on iOS, run `pod install` in the `ios` directory and then rebuild and re-run the app.

  • If this happens while testing with Jest, check out docs how to integrate AsyncStorage with it: https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/advanced/jest

If none of these fix the issue, please open an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/react-native-async-storage/issues
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
      This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
```

This is how I'm building the app,it always works but with AsyncStorage I'm getting the above error:

```
cd C:\xampp\htdocs\SoFood && cd android  && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: Did you try deleting package-lock.json ?

Comment: No, will try it for sure